# Was ist ein Tröglein?

Tags: meaning

Im Märchen [Das Tröglein](http://www.muenchen-flughafentransfer.de/maerchen0001.htm) baut der Sohn ein hölzernes Tröglein. Was ist das?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***"Tröglein"*** ist hier der Dimitutiv von *"[Trog](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trog)"* und bedeutet in der Definition von Duden:

> großes, längliches, offenes Gefäß, das je nach Verwendungszweck meist aus Holz oder Stein gefertigt ist

Heute versteht man unter Trog meist eine Futtereinrichtung für Tiere in der Landwirtschaft (eng. *feeder trough*). Früher wurden aber oft auch Behälter zur Aufbewahrung von Lebensmitteln so bezeichnet. Einzig der Salztrog ist in der Küche noch bekannt:

[Bild eines Salztrogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeEIG.jpg)

In dem Märchen wird also die Herstellung eines kleinen Trogs beschrieben. Dies haben auch die Brüder Grimm in ihrem Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache in ihrer Defintion von *["Tröglein"](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT12109)* zitiert:

> *'ei', antwortete das kind, 'ich mach ein tröglein, daraus sollen vater und mutter essen, wenn ich grosz bin'*

Answer (score 10):

Das ist einer der möglichen [Diminutive](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Diminutiv&language=0&project=1) von [Trog](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trog), alternativ wäre auch Trögchen möglich (siehe auch [canoo zur Umlautung `o => ö` vor dem Suffix -lein](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/lein.html)).